# Add labels and vertical line on matplotlib (outside plot area)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2020',0.1,0.3,'cat1','csv'],\
                  ['1/1/2020',0.4,0.7,'cat1','excel'],\
                  ['1/1/2020',1.7,2.3,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0,0.3,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0.4,0.5,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0.5,0.7,'cat1','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',1.1,1.3,'cat1','excel']],\
                     columns = ['date','start','end','cat','source'])
```

Each row of the df contains range of values to be colored and the color group (cat). I can plot a graph like the following with the following code:
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))

```
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    plt.barh(r['date'], width=r['end']-r['start'],
             left=r['start'], color='y' if r['cat']=='cat1' else 'g')
```

[image]

My issue is, I would like to add zoning details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question can be broken down into 2 parts:

**1. Plot textbox outside the xy plot**

```
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=1)
plt.text(0, .9, "textstr", fontsize=14, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure,verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
```

The values of 0 and 0.9 can be adjusted manually for your purpose.

**2. draw a vertical line on the xy plot**

```
plt.axvline(x=5,color='r', linewidth = 5)
```